# C doesn't recognize var - I must be overlooking something simple.

Tags: c, variables, for-loop, microcontroller

From error I think code in print() is not seeing the counter in for().n.b. code is for Propeller microcontroller. for() worked without problems in past. Much thanks

```
#include "simpletools.h"  // for print on my microcontroller platform
void main(void) {
    for(int x = 1; x <= 20; x++); {
        // *** error next line> error: 'x' undeclared (first use in this function)
        print("x = %d\n", x);
        high(14);
        pause(500);
        low(14);
        pause(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: You close the scope of the `for` with your semicolon...

Comment: I was about to post my usual rant about `void main`, but it's likely correct for an embedded system like the microcontroller platform you're using. BTW, is it really `print` and not `printf`?

Comment: Many compilers will warn you that a semi followed by a brace like that is a likely unintentional empty body. Are you sure you've turned up the warning level on your compiler to eleven?

Comment: Everyone's right. Compiling with -Wall should help a lot, and the fact that you closed out your for-loop with the semicolon is definitely part of the issue, if not the issue itself. I also believe you have to declare the int i before you use it in the loop, at least with C99. I'm not sure if that part is true, but this is what I was told.

Comment: Keith:
I think the void on main might be required for uCon, but I'd like to read the rant. Got a link?

Comment: Keith:
Yes, print() - not printf(). printf() creates some oddity which I can't figure yet in a pattern. print() works fine with %

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try removing the semicolon after `for` but before the `{`.

Change this:

`for(int x = 1; x <= 20; x++); {`

to this:

`for(int x = 1; x <= 20; x++) {`

The `;` ends the `for` loop.  What you have done in your code is have a complete `for` loop followed by an unrelated block of code.  The `x` is only visible within the scope of the `for` loop, which means up to that errant semicolon.

Comment: I added some explanation about *why* the semicolon is wrong.

Comment: On top of this, also, I was told that C doesn't like it when you declare variables in the loop declaration. So, that could be tried as well - declaring the variable before the loop, then initializing/using it inside of the loop.

Comment: Super thanks - the solution and the reason.
One semicolon can ruin a whole day. I'm not big on declare in the args, but got desperate trying to find answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
void main(void) {
    int x = 1;
    for(; x <= 20; x++) {
        print("x = %d\n", x);
        high(14);
        pause(500);
        low(14);
        pause(500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question said "C Language" right? So I think you should declare the value "int x" on top first.